# mysql compare 2 timestamp column on same row to a search range

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp

I am using mysql and need to find user who is within a timestamp range. One column is to note when user comes in and another is to note when user goes out.

```
         In                      Out                     Name
Row1    2017-01-10 08:00:00     2017-01-10 15:00:00      Sam
Row2    2017-01-10 11:00:00     2017-01-10 17:00:00      Tim


SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE In > '2017-01-10 09:00:00' AND Out < '2017-01-10 13:00:00'
```

OR (Before anyone comes in and after they leave)

```
  SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE In > '2017-01-10 07:00:00' AND Out < '2017-01-10 18:00:00'
```

This should return Both user as they are in office during the time range from 8am to 1pm or 7am to 6pm. But it returns an empty row. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no record with given Between time in your table. So returning nothing.

Your query should be like

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE '2017-01-10 09:00:00' BETWEEN IN AND OUT
AND  '2017-01-10 13:00:00' BETWEEN IN AND OUT
```

**Edit:** From comments

When we talk about range, we specify 2 values.  So in mentioned 2 values range there is only 1 user. If your concern to return all possible users, then replace `AND` with `OR`.

So for your case, query will be

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE '2017-01-10 09:00:00' BETWEEN IN AND OUT
OR  '2017-01-10 13:00:00' BETWEEN IN AND OUT
```

Comment: Thank you but, It does not return the 2 users.  Sam is in at 8am, Tim is in at 11am. Search range 9am to 1pm which should return both users.

Comment: Thank you. OR works but I noticed If I set my search range for example WHERE '2017-01-10 07:00:00' BETWEEN IN AND OUT OR  '2017-01-10 18:00:00' BETWEEN IN AND OUT  ... I don't get any result. I should get both users as they fall in the time range. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try the formal query like u did, but with OR operator  `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE In > '2017-01-10 07:00:00' OR  Out < '2017-01-10 18:00:00' `  @lee

Comment: Thank but if I have another date: 2017-01-09 14:30:00  it also returns it which is incorrect as I need to search only within the range

Comment: Then again you came to range, The first answer is fit for range of users..